# constexpr and mutable member and implicit copy-ctor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, copy-constructor, constexpr

The following code compiles in clang 7+, but not in 5 & 6 (with c++17 and c++14). 
The problem for clang 5 and 6 seems to be that the implicit copy ctor reads from the mutable member `x`.

Can anybody tell me, if the whole construction is standard-compliant (c++17), or if the program is ill-formed? Or was there a change in the standard regarding the implicit copy-ctor which might not be implemented in the earlier clang versions?

```
struct Foo {

    int a;
    mutable int x{};

    constexpr Foo() : a(0) {}

    //constexpr Foo(const Foo& other) : a(other.a) {} // <- with this line it works on Clang 5 & 6, too
};

struct FooFactory {

    static constexpr auto create() {
        auto f = Foo{};       
        return f;
    }
};

int main() {

    constexpr Foo f = FooFactory::create();
    ++f.x;
}
```

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/uJKHUW).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-formed C++17 program.  A constexpr function can of course read (and write) **non-constant** variables:

```
constexpr int f(int i) {
  int j=i;
  ++j;
  return i+j;  // neither is a constant expression
}
```

The [rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.7) is that anything examined in a constant expression must either be a constant *or* have its lifetime begun **during** the expression’s evaluation.  In your case, the lifetime of `create`’s `f.x` plainly begins within the evaluation of the constant expression that is the **initialization** of `main`’s `f`.  It is true, however, that no `Foo` object can be copied by a constant expression that does not also create that object, whether or not it is `constexpr`.

The only other candidate problem is if the copy constructor were not constexpr, but those requirements are very **weak**.  The only relevant ones are that every (non-variant) member be initialized, which is certainly satisfied, and that it be usable in at least one constant expression, which has been demonstrated.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I mentioned the read from a non-constant member, because that was a note clang 6 printet after the this-is-not-a-constant-expression-error.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ill-formed. For the reference, here is simplified code, which fails on all compilers:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    mutable int x{};
    constexpr Foo() : a(0) {}

};

int main() {
    constexpr Foo f;
    constexpr Foo f1 = f;
}
```

As per [expr.const] 7.7,

> A variable is usable in constant expressions after its initializing
>   declaration is encountered if
>   it is a constexpr variable,
>
> or ...  (3.5) a non-mutable
>   subobject or reference member of any of the above.

This disqualifies default copy constructors.

Comment: Clang probably doesn't complain about OP's code because NRVO kicks in. Adding `constexpr Foo f1 = f;` indeed causes a error.

Comment: Good catch, this seems to be the reason! Thank you guys!

Comment: This simplification doesn't seem equivalent. It is not required that a `constexpr` function only use constant expressions. As I see it, the original factory function calls the default constructor of `Foo` to make `f`, then initializes its return object with the copy constructor. Neither requires `f` to be usable in constant expressions. The initialization `constexpr Foo f = FooFactory::create()` doesn't directly call any constructors. `f` is initialized by the call's evaluation. Thus, the full-expression of `f`'s initialization is just a call to a `constexpr` function, which is allowed.

Comment: That’s [expr.const]/3, not 7.7, and is part of the C++20 draft, not 17, and the bullet doesn’t correspond to variables, but objects or references.